# Array sorting by class property in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have a class called Order, for each order of burgers I do at a burger restaurant.
I have an array of all the orders that have been placed today (Order[]) called orderstoday
I want to sort orderstoday[] by the time each order have been placed, which can be obtained by Order.timestamp.
How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please show the classes and the structure

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Note that the question mentions alphabetical sort; however, the answers there will also solve your problem of sorting by date.

Comment: using System.Linq;

orders.OrderBy(order=>order.TimeStamp)  You can  check this page http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending

Comment: thanks miguel that helped me